# Minimum number of subsets in set given a set of mutually exclusive integer pairs

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, algorithms, linear-programming

Given a set $\\A$ with $\\n$ distinct integers and a set of $\\k$ distinct integer pairs $\\( a_i, b_i)$, where$\ \{a_i,b_i\}\in A $, what would be an (efficient) algorithm to calculate the minimum number of subsets in which $\\A$ should be divided so that for every pair $\\( a_i, b_i)$, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are not both in the same subset?

Is this a variant of the NP-hard [multicut](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2009/Lectures/lecture_18.pdf) problem?

Comment: I think you are computing the chromatic number of a graph, which is also NP-hard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity)

Comment: Seems to be what I was looking for, thanks!